# How to click a button on PDF inside iframe

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have a fillable pdf on my website displaying inside an iframe. I created a Save button at the end of it through adobe acrobat professional, it is suppose to trigger Save As action ... However I cannot click on that button. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you using to display the PDF in the browser? The browser's own PDF viewing component, or Acrobat's?

Comment: That explains it. The browser's own PDF viewer is too dumb to understand buttons and actions. Use the PDF viewing component of Acrobat/Reader instead.

Comment: Adobe is not supporting chrome any more ! Edge is not supported either ... pretty much leaves us with firefox, IE and Safari... Works fine on IE, not so sure about Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Chrome (in other words, Google) is no longer supporting the plug-in technology needed. This is a little bit of a difference. Safari should work well, not sure about Firefox either (it is such a memory hog that I had to dump it). What you could help to do is "persuade" Google to provide a less dumb PDF viewer (it would be sufficient if it supported ISO 32000:2…)